# Casting to CFStringRef with ARC crashes iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sockets

I'm following a [simple socket tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) which is written without ARC in mind. I'm injecting the ideas from the tutorial into my app, which is all written with ARC enabled.

I'm running into a problem with this specific line of code:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)self.SERVER, self.PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

which under ARC does not compile, so i tried both of the 'fix-it's', one of which is:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.SERVER, self.PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

however this line is causing me some issues. My app crashes on what seems like an internal call 'objc_msgsend'giving me an exc_bad_access error.

Any ideas on how to fix this line for ARC?

**edit: my debugging skills failed me before posting this. the cause of the problem is not the reason stated above but something else in my code. I think it has something to do with handling incoming streams.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the naming convention for methods and properties, as Nikolai correctly pointed out, I suspect that your are not retaining your streams.

The should be declared as `strong` if they are properties, can you please show the rest of your code?

Comment: i had the code from the tutorial copied and pasted into a class, and in a method inside of my personal-class, i had alloced and init the tutorial code. i think arc was releasing this object before i got the response, causing the issue. making the tutorial-code-class into a property with the strong keyword fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code is good—the names of your methods are not: `SERVER` should be `server` and `PORT` likewise. You should definitely adopt Objective-C coding style.